# Hash change event works from time to time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a tabbing system that is meant to switch between two `div`s on my page. It worked well until I decided to make it work with the URL (more specifically, to react when `onhashchange` event occurs). It works from time to time only. I don't know where the problem is in that tiny piece of code and it dives me crazy.

```
$(function() {
    if ("onhashchange" in window) {
      console.log("onhashchanged is supported");
    } else {
      console.log("onhashchanged is not supported")
    }
    window.onhashchange = function() {
      var hash = (window.location.hash.substr(1) != "") ?  window.location.hash.substr(1) : "articles";

      var tabId = hash + "t";
      var tabBtnId = hash + "tb";

      $("div.tabbar > div.tabbarButton").removeClass("current");
      $("div.tabbar > div.tabbarButton#" + tabBtnId).addClass("current");

      var $tabs = $(".tabsContent");
      $tabs.find(".tab").removeClass("current");
      $tabs.find(".tab#" + tabId).addClass("current");
    };

    $("div.tabbar > div.tabbarButton").click(function() {
      var selectedTabId = $(this).prop("id");
      var hashVal = "#" + selectedTabId.substr(0, selectedTabId.length - 2);
      window.location.assign(hashVal);
      console.log(hashVal);
    });
  });
```

**My guess:** I suppose the `hashchange` event occurs before the DOM is ready and the function is not called in my code (because it is located in the `$(function(){ /*...*/ })`), but if this is the reason, then where can I put the event handler so that it works with the jQuery's operations?

Answer (score 0):

Use the jquery way to bind the event:

```
$(window).hashchange( function(){ /* ... */ });
```

And then immedialty afer that trigger the hashchange event yourself:

```
$(window).hashchange();
```

This way you can be sure that your function is triggered when the script is loaded.